# How to implement Antiforgerytokens with partial views in mvc4?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to implement antiforgerytoken in my project. I am able to implement it when making ajax call below.

```
 function docDelete(id) {
        var _upload_id = $("#docId").val();
        var _comments = $("#name").val();
        var forgeryId = $("#forgeryToken").val();

        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            url: '/DeleteDocument/Delete',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'VerificationToken': forgeryId
            },
            data: { _upload_id: _upload_id, _comments: _comments },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#dvSuccess').val(data);
                Getgridata(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

above code works fine. But in some cases i am making ajax request as below.

```
var forgeryId = $("#forgeryToken").val();
function GetGrid() {
    $.ajax(
    {

        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        url: '/Dashboard/GetGridData',
        headers: {
            'VerificationToken': forgeryId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dvmyDocuments').html("");
            $('#dvmyDocuments').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Above code does not send any token to below method.

```
private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            string cookieToken = string.Empty;
            string formToken = string.Empty;
            string tokenValue = request.Headers["VerificationToken"]; // read the header key and validate the tokens.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
            {
                string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(',');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                    formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                }
            }

            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken); // this validates the request token.
        }
    }
```

In layout.cshtml i have implmented code to get token.

```
   <script>
 @functions{
 public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
 {
 string cookieToken, formToken;
 AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
 return cookieToken + "," + formToken;
 }
 }
</script>
    <input type="hidden" id="forgeryToken" value="@GetAntiForgeryToken()" />
```

The variable tokenValue  catching null each time. So what i understood is through headers i am not able to send token value. I tried many alternatives. So anyone suggest me how can i overcome this issue? Thank you in advance.

I tried as below still i am getting null value.

```
var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
var headers = {};
headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;
alert(token);
var forgeryId = JSON.stringify($("#forgeryToken").val());
function GetGrid() {
    $.ajax(
    {

        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",

        cache: false,
        url: '/Dashboard/GetGridData',
        cache: false,
        headers: headers,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dvmyDocuments').html("");
            $('#dvmyDocuments').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does the `#forgeryToken` came from? The hidden input created by the `AntiForgeryToken` don't have an ID, but it has a name attribute of  `__RequestVerificationToken`

Comment: I am facing problem in catching token value and sending through via headers so is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found problem. Actually i have created sepearte js files and sending headers. In js files i am not able to generate tokens. above code working fine in .cshtml. I am wondered is there any solution to generate tokens in js files